# iOS app doesn't show edit notifications in the inbox

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app, global-inbox, notification-bar

Viewing SE in a desktop browser, I get edit notifications in the inbox:

[image]

But in the iOS app (version 1.2.2), I do not see edit notifications in the inbox:

[image]

Comment: @ShadowWizard You just edited that question to include edit notifications!  Should I really be penalized by having my question marked as a duplicate when that question didn't mention edit notifications?

Comment: It mentioned **all** items, edit is one of them, it just wasn't clear enough. Nobody is expecting you to always find dupes yourself, that's what we got other users here. :)

Comment: There's also no "penalty" for having your question marked as duplicate

Comment: @mhlester Well technically it does move you slightly in the direction of a question ban.

Comment: Technically yes. But you're pretty safe on Meta. Lots of great minds thinking alike :)